# ng-bind-html content invisible issue in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used ng-bind-html like this

```
<p ng-bind-html="{{content.content}}">
</p>
```

but it didn't appear. But when I inspect, they are there. How come? It's not css issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive takes an expression and evaluates it. So you should not put it into `{{ }}`. Try this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="content.content"></p>
```

Curly braces are used for expression interpolation, so its result is not an expression any more. However `ngBindHtml` needs an expression, because it passes this expression to some sanitize services to clean up from unsafe content.